# Use a Text Based Formula from one cell as the actual formula in another

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a scenario that i am unable to figure out.  What i am trying to do is build up a complex formula in a cell that is text based.  I then want to use the result of that text based formula as the actual formula in another cell.  Is this even possible?

Example:

`B1` = 2

`B2` = 3

`B4` = `="B1+B2"` in a text format so the result looks like: **B1+B2**

I want to use the value of B4 as the formula in B5 so that the end result in cell B5 is:  **5**

I have tried in B5 `=B4` but that just results in the text value of B4 which is `B1+B2` again.  I also tried a few other options and they all fail which is why i am here.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: also see: https://superuser.com/questions/253353/excel-function-that-evaluates-a-string-as-if-it-were-a-formula

Comment: Thanks!  Do i just delete my question then since its a duplicate?  I guess i searched for the wrong keywords!

Comment: Feel free to leave it, as other may stumble here before finding another and the links will help them

Comment: Is there a way to mark yours as the answer and give you kudos?